# Window Workflow Foundation tutorial on VS11

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, visual-studio-2012

There isnt a single tutorial about Window Workflow Foundation on VS11.
Any example that shows how to start using Window Workflow Foundation on VS 2008, cant be implemented on VS11.

I will be grateful for any tutorial about **Window Workflow Foundation** on **VS11**.

Comment: Visual Studio 2011 isn't released yet, it's out for testing purposes.  Hence you should count on limited resources at least until it's been released officially. ;)

Comment: FYI, there is not nor will here ever be any product named "Visual Studio 2011". You are referring to "Visual Studio 11". The "11" refers to the version number, not the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorials for VS11 will not be very different that the ones for Visual Studio 2010. It sounds to me like you have not done the VS10 tutorials yet so take a look at [Want to learn WF4?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/10/13/want-to-learn-windows-workflow-4-wf4.aspx)